# How can I reset the paginator in PrimeFaces DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have the problem that when I load the table for the first time, set the paginator for example to page 3 and reload the table with new data, the paginator is still on page 3. Is there a smart way to check if the table is successfully rendered and reset the pagionator to the first page?

I've tried clicking a button and do this with ajax but this is no solution because my implementation is a bit tricky. So my first thoughts are to reset it every time the table is loaded.

Current Implementation:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="resetHistoryDataTablePaginator invisible">
  <f:ajax onevent="PF('historyDataWidget').paginator.setPage(0)"/>
</h:commandButton>

$('.resetHistoryDataTablePaginator').click();
```

The problem is that this works but creates a lot of problems with my page. So can you tell me the way to reset the paginator after every table load?

Comment: What do you refer with a table load? Which actions do trigger a table reload?

Comment: try "PF('historyDataWidget').getPaginator.setPage(0)"